# Use of unresolved identifer for data storage in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

Help with this swift 3 error. We are trying to somehow store the number of characters in each phrase, in this case into anagram1length and anagram2length as per source that comes from https://www.raywenderlich.com/77981/make-letter-word-game-uikit-swift-part-1. Concern here is the following two lines of code in swift 3 giving us an error use of unresolved identifier 'count':

```
let anagram1length = count(anagram1)
let anagram2length = count(anagram2)
```

From the following function:

```
  func dealRandomAnagram () {
    //1
    assert(level.anagrams.count > 0, "no level loaded")

    //2
    let randomIndex = randomNumber(minX:0, maxX:UInt32(level.anagrams.count-1))
    let anagramPair = level.anagrams[randomIndex]

    //3
    let anagram1 = anagramPair[0] as! String
    let anagram2 = anagramPair[1] as! String

    //4
    let anagram1length = count(anagram1)
    let anagram2length = count(anagram2)

    //5
    print("phrase1[\(anagram1length)]: \(anagram1)")
    print("phrase2[\(anagram2length)]: \(anagram2)")

    //calculate the tile size
    let tileSide = ceil(ScreenWidth * 0.9 / CGFloat(max(anagram1length, anagram2length))) - TileMargin

    //get the left margin for first tile
    var xOffset = (ScreenWidth - CGFloat(max(anagram1length, anagram2length)) * (tileSide + TileMargin)) / 2.0

    //adjust for tile center (instead of the tile's origin)
    xOffset += tileSide / 2.0

    //initialize target list
    targets = []

    //create targets
    for (index, letter) in anagram2length.enumerate(anagram2) {
      if letter != " " {
        let target = TargetView(letter: letter, sideLength: tileSide)
        target.center = CGPointMake(xOffset + CGFloat(index)*(tileSide + TileMargin), ScreenHeight/4)

        gameView.addSubview(target)
        targets.append(target)
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial is obviously written in an old Swift version.

In the current Swift 3 version it's usually

```
let anagram1length = anagram1.characters.count
let anagram2length = anagram2.characters.count
```

Comment: That's true. However, this solution is not helping in this case. If I use what you suggested, then this line 'for (index, letter) in anagram2length.enumerate(anagram2)' failed.

Comment: It does help if you translate the entire code to your current Swift version. You probably mean `for (index, letter) in anagram2.characters.enumerated()`. Your syntax `anagram2length.enumerate(anagram2)` doesn't even compile in the old Swift version.

Comment: Converting entire function to Swift 3 worked. Thanks.

Comment: Please rate my question with your opinion. Thanks.